# cURL operation returns with odd formatting, how to get normal results?

Tags: php, curl, calculator

Hi im trying to write a currency converting php script, utilizing the Google Calculator API via cURL. (file_get_contents doesnt work in my hosting server).

the URL im trying to get data from is

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1usd=?idr

the result of loading from a browser:

> {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "8 928.57143 Indonesian rupiahs",error:
>   "",icc: true}

but my script returns :

> {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "8Â 928.57143 Indonesian rupiahs",error:
>   "",icc: true}

as you can see on the rhs part there are white space differences, and a funny A character, hampering my rounding operations.

my script before exploding & rounding etc: ($url has been set to the above value)

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    $rawresult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

how do i get the same formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are receiving there is `C2 A0` in UTF-8 encoding. That's the non-breaking space (NBSP). You can either use [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/utf8_decode) to cope or just set your pages to UTF-8 charset.

When decoded, the character becomes `chr(0xA0)` in Latin-1. So you might want to use a `preg_split('/\s/u'` rather than just exploding on a space.

The other alternative is to add the `Accept-Charset: ASCII` header when requesting the resource via cURL. (Then Google returns an ordinary space here. Just a solution for Google though, not many websites honour such HTTP features.)